# How to cancel a synchronous IO operation?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, file-io, delphi-10.3-rio

I wrote this code to test how async IO cancellation works... But the read operation it's not canceled... When I call `CancelSynchronousIo`, the execution is blocked until thread finishes and then I get `Element not found` error. Do you have any idea what I did wrong ?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BStartRead: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    BCancel: TButton;
    procedure BStartReadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    T1: TMyThread;
    procedure LogMsg(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_USER;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var Buff: TBytes;
    hFile: THandle;
    StrMsg, FileName: String;
    N: Cardinal;
begin
 SetLength(Buff, 200000000);
 FileName:= '...some file...';
 hFile:= CreateFile(PChar('\\?\'+FileName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
 if hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
  StrMsg:= 'Start reading...'; SendMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@StrMsg), 0);
  if ReadFile(hFile, Buff[0], 200000000, N, nil)
   then StrMsg:= 'Successfuly terminated.'
   else StrMsg:= 'Error: canceled !';
  SendMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@StrMsg), 0);
  CloseHandle(hFile);
 end
 else begin
  StrMsg:= 'Error: failed to open file !';
  SendMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@StrMsg), 0);
 end;
end;

//---- VCL -----

procedure TForm1.BStartReadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 T1:= TMyThread.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.BCancelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if CancelSynchronousIo(T1.Handle) then Memo1.Lines.Add('Cancel result: success')
  else Memo1.Lines.Add('Cancel result: '+SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;

procedure TForm1.LogMsg(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
 case Msg.Msg of
   WM_USER: Memo1.Lines.Add(PString(Msg.WParam)^.Substring(0));
 end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It is possible that at the time `CancelSynchronousIo()` is being called, the thread is not actually inside `ReadFile()`, either because it hasn't been called yet, or has already finished.  `CancelSynchronousIo()` only cancel's I/Os that are actively pending at the moment `CancelSynchronousIo()` is called.  Cancel requests are not remembered for future I/Os, or I/Os that have already completed

Comment: I will check that... But why is it not returning immediately if it does not find any operation in progress?

Comment: No, the operation is in progress... It can't be otherwise, because I hit the Cancel button after I see the "start reading" message and the operation is not completed because it takes some time to read 200 MB.

Comment: Have you read [Canceling Pending I/O Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/canceling-pending-i-o-operations) yet?

Comment: Yes, but the example is writen in C and I don't fully understand...

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are not using `ReadFile()` asynchronously with an `OVERLAPPED` record, and using `CancelIoEx()` to cancel it?

Comment: Yes, but the explanation is too long to write it here...